# closesocket() call on socket in windows takes 20 sec

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, delay, closesocket

I'm trying to close socket on windows from closesocket(), but it takes 20 sec to complete. at first I thought it was about linger interval, although I was not setting anything with setsockopt by linger, so I added such code:

```
linjer lobj;
lobj.l_onoff = 1;
lobj.l_linger = 0;

sz = sizeof(lobj);

setsockopt(s_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char *) &lobj, sz);
```

but it still does not help.

any ideas? I just want to close connection, doesnt matter if its gracefull or abortion, just want to close it as soon as possible.

P.S. it takes exactly 20 sec.

```
lobj.l_onoff = 1; 
lobj.l_linger = 0; 
sz = sizeof(lobj); 
setsockopt(s_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char *) &lobj, sz);
lobj.l_onoff = -1;
lobj.l_linger = -1; 
getsockopt(s_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, (char *) &lobj, &sz); 
log << "Option 1:" << lobj.l_linger << ".\n"; 
log << "Option 2:" << lobj.l_onoff << ".\n";
closesocket(s_);
```

this code prints option1 = 0 and option2 = 1, so it really sets option correctly.

Also, observing from wireshark, it sends RST at the beginning of whole delay.

plus, closesocket() returns 0.

P.S. I have set SO_REUSADDR, can it be causing it?

Comment: Please including complete working code that shows the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not, I can answer any question but cannot paste code, sorry about that

Comment: Did you try with `l_onoff = 0` ? Or with `SO_DONTLINGER` ?

Comment: yes, as I said before adding this code I was not setting anything with setsockopt, so it was l_onoff=0, I checked with getsockopt also

Comment: If it's a TCP socket: do you call shutdown(SD_BOTH) on the socket? Otherwise the socket implementation might have to wait until all data is sent and no further data is received on the connection.

Comment: it should not wait, I turned on linger with timeout of 0, so it just sends RST packet

Comment: @rpress That's not correct, and calling `shutdown()` wouldn't fix it if it was.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't post the code you can't ask the question here. Those are the rules.

However the only way `closesocket()` can take any measurable time at all is if:

- there is a lot of pending outgoing data, and
- you have set a positive SO_LINGER timeout.

You can only get a delay of 20 seconds by setting a positive SO_LINGER timeout of >= 20 seconds *and* having a lot of pending outgoing data *and* probably a peer that isn't reading.

If you had left SO_LINGER strictly alone, which you should, or set it to false, or true with a zero timeout, `closesocket()` is asynchronous and returns immediately, and in the latter case you would also have reset the connection.

*Ergo* either you haven't done what you claimed or your observations are faulty. Possibly it is the final `send()` which is blocking.

It would be interesting to know whether this `closesocket()` call returned -1 and if so what the error value was.

Comment: whole code that is using that socket is quite big, I can post only those parts that are interesting to us :)

Comment: Please post your code *in your question.* You can see for yourself that it is completely and utterly illegible when posted in comments. I'm not even gong to even try to decipher that mess.

Comment: sorry about that.
yes, I'm not sure but I think peer isn't reading data, it may be that some data is being retransmitted but I want to close that connection, without waiting for anything.

Comment: Sure you're closing the same socket you set abortive LINGER on?

Comment: yes, after that code comes closesocket(s_)

Comment: I also attached gdb when its stuck, last 2 frames are from ntdll!zwclose()